# Using processing libraries in processing.js

Tags: java, javascript, canvas, processing, processing.js

For those that don't know, [Processing](http://processing.org) is a great Java library =for rendering nice visualizations of data and serves as a wrapper for JOGL.

[Processing.js](http://processingjs.org) is the Javascript port of this library.

In order to create a processing applet inside HTML, you need 3 things.

1. processing.js
2. anything.html
3. anything.pde   // Processing program

I'm basically trying out the js version and the problem is that if any libraries are included in the pde, it won't load inside the canvas.

---

Here are 2 examples:

1. [This](http://pastebin.com/AbXYQVDY) is an example that spawns some basic shapes with no libraries required.
2. [This](http://pastebin.com/V4ZJgumZ) is an example that uses the handy fisica library. If I try it in the same format as this then it will not load.

---

I have 2 hypotheses:

1. There is some configuration that must be done before using any libraries in processing.js.
2. All libraries for Processing are put in the default library folder \Processing\modes\java. This is obviously not being reached by the HTML file so perhaps there is another way to add the files into the application?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742617

Comment: @ChrisF This question was how. That question was why.

Comment: I wasn't 100% sure, that's why I just presented the link and didn't vote to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Processing.js does not support Processing libraries. This because they are compiled Java bytecode, not Java source code. For physics, you could use Box2D.js. See [a tutorial](http://processingjs.org/source/box2d/box2d.html) on processingjs.org. For more information on the limitations of Processing.js as compared to Processing, see our [P5 quick start guide](http://processingjs.org/reference/articles/p5QuickStart).

Comment: There ARE some libraries which are 'cross-platform', that is, they work with (at least) Java and Javascript. Two examples I know of are [Guido](https://github.com/fjenett/Guido) and [RiTa](http://www.rednoise.org/RiTa/), but there may well be others...