# Embed Processing .pde file with fisica library into html

Tags: java, javascript, html, embed, processing

I want to embed a .pde file with the fisica library into a webpage.  This will not work with processing.js (because it is using a library), but I was wondering if there was any other way to do it?  I looked at [Using processing libraries in processing.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681540/using-processing-libraries-in-processing-js), but it does not give a solution.  Does that mean that it is impossible?

Thanks in advance,

-Peperononew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy it as a java applet.This used to come out of the box in older versions of Processing, but have been removed. Although there is a tool, that you can install from tools menu that does that. It's called [AppletMaker](http://www.lagers.org.uk/appletutil/index.html) by [Peter Lager](http://www.lagers.org.uk). Go Tools > add tool> AppletMaker > install. It will work with processing's or java's libraries.